# How to check via content provider whether there is already a specific record in my SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, persistence, android-contentprovider

Basically, I have a list of items that I have downloaded over an API and at some point, I record some of those items into my SQLite Database. I perform the CRUD operations such as (Insert, Query, Update, Delete) via a content provider and now I would like to know **how to implement a function using or in my content provider that checks whether a specific record already exists in my database so that I would not need to insert it again.** More specifically, for my code, each recorded item has an id (which is not the primary key) that was received from the API and I would like to check against that id (which of course is stored into a column in my database).

Comment: Can you post what u have as of now

Comment: There is no need for that, I am just asking for a boolean method that receives as a parameter a String code and returns the answer whether the code already is in the databse

Answer (score 0):

Define the column with the `UNIQUE` constraint and use `INSERT OR IGNORE` when inserting.

e.g.

Create the table like :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS atable (id INTEGER UNIQUE, mydata TEXT);
```

Insert like :-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO atable VALUES(10,'myvalue');
```

Obviously just adapt this as needed according to your top secret mustn't be shown code. :)